# Pass multiple variable value into URL in python

Tags: python

I have below code to get data using url. I pass ticker value from text file and its successful and its;works (part-1)
but as code per part-2, when I pass multiple value using multiple variable by raw_input(), its give **error "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"**

Part-1

```
ticker = line.strip();
url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s.ns&a=08&b=08&c=2015&d=08&e=08&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv" % ticker
r = requests.get(url)
```

Part-2

```
ticker = line.strip();
url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s.ns&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s&g=d&ignore=.csv" %ticker %a %b %c %d %e %f
r = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing those *format* parameters correctly:

```
url = "...?s=%s.ns&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s&g=d&ignore=.csv"%(ticker, a, b, c, d, e, f)
#                                                                 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

When passing the parameters for formatting, you should pass them all in a tuple, and not independently.

Considering the number of your parameters, you can instead use the new style formatting to have a more readable code.

An example usage is shown below:

```
c = 'a={a}&b={b}'.format(a=1, b=2)
# 'a=1&b=2'
```

So in your case, you would pass your paramters as named arguments viz. `ticker, a, b, c, d, e, f`

You can learn more about string formatting at [pyformat](https://pyformat.info/)